# How do I call a method in the parentDelegate of a delegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I have a method I want to call that returns a Bool in the parentDelegate of the delegate to the object I need the information in. How do I make this call method? The compiler complains about a weak reference to the delegate.

`x = [self.delegate.parentDelegate method_I_want_to_call];`

`Property parentDelegate not found on object of type __weak id <currentClassDelegate>`

Comment: What do you mean by "the compiler complains?" The most likely problem here is that `x` is a weak variable, but it's difficult to know from this description.

Comment: @RobNapier added to question.

Comment: This is complaining that the `currentClassDelegate` protocol does not define `parentDelegate` as a property. It's not related to weakness.

Comment: Can you add more context about the delegate and the parent delegate and what you want to achieve maybe there is another approach to solve your issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution is to call a protocol method on `self.delegate`, and then have that class call a method on the parentDelegate. That way your code is more encapsulated. Alternatively, you could add a `parentDelegate` property to your `currentClassDelegate` protocol.

But if you have a good reason to do it the way you described, then this will work:

```
// Import whatever class will be used for self.delegate
#import "MarcusDelegate.h"

...

// First we make sure it's safe to cast self.delegate to MarcusDelegate
if ([self.delegate isKindOfClass:[MarcusDelegate class]]) {
    id parentDelegate = [(MarcusDelegate *)self.delegate parentDelegate];

    if ([parentDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(method_I_want_to_call)]) {
        [parentDelegate method_I_want_to_call];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"WARNING: self.delegate.parentDelegate can't handle method_I_want_to_call!");
    }
} else {
    NSLog(@"WARNING: self.delegate is not a MarcusDelegate object!");
}
```

You can see why this is not the recommended approach. It destroys some of the flexibility of programming with protocols. Your code shouldn't break if some other class is set on `self.delegate`.

This works too, but it preserves the flexibility of protocol programming:

```
// in the first class
[self.delegate callThatMethodOnParent];

// then in the delegate class
- (void)callThatMethodOnParent
    [self.delegate method_I_want_to_call];
}
```

Or you could stop pretending it's a protocol:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) MarcusDelegate *delegate;
```

Comment: I would definitely go with the second version of what Sterling wrote. Objects with delegates shouldn't be aware of the delegate's capabilities other than those necessary.

An object shouldn't know that it's delegate has another delegate. It should only know what it can tell its delegate. It's a one way communication channel.